# JavaScript shop script won’t function as intended

Tags: javascript, confirmation

I’m trying to make this shop script to include these criteria’s:

1. Balance can not go under 0
2. When there is not enough funds, voucher will be used.
3. It logs both the use of the voucher and the success confirmations.

Right now the balance does go under zero, and the voucher doesn’t get used... maybe it’s obvious but Im being driven insane.

Also, any tips to optimize this code?

Thank you! I’m sorry if this is painfully obvious. I’m completely new to this!

```
var total = 500;
var balance = 400;
var voucher = 100;
useVoucher = true;

if ( (total > balance) || (balance < 0) ) {
console.log("Insufficient funds. The total is " + total + "$ and you only have a balance of " + balance + "$.");
} else if (useVoucher = true) {
total = total - voucher
console.log(voucher + "$ Voucher applied. The new total is " + total + "$.");
} else {
console.log("You can't afford this item");
} 

if ((balance - total < 0) && balance > total); {
console.log("Success! You have a new balance of " + (balance - total) + "$.");
}
```

Comment: It should be `useVoucher === true`. At the moment you're assigning `true` to `useVoucher` not checking to see if `useVoucher` is `true`

Comment: Good point, thank you! I had no idea. It didn’t work, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You have to check if you can use voucher. It happens if you don't have enough balance, but you have enough balance using the voucher.

In this situation use the voucher.

Than check if you have enough balance to pay or not.

Here is the code:

```
var total = 500;
var balance = 400;
var voucher = 100;
useVoucher = true;


if (total > balance     // Not enough balance
      && useVoucher     // You can use the voucher
      && total - voucher <= balance) {  // Total minus voucher is under balance
  console.log(voucher + "$ Voucher applied. The new total is " + total + "$.");
  // IN this case use voucher
  total = total - voucher;

  // Would be better to check here if total is under 0, 
  // otherwise in the next few lines of code you will increase your balance.
} 

if (total <= balance) {   // Check if you have enough balance
  balance = balance - total;
  console.log("Success! You have a new balance of " + balance + "$.");
} else {                  // Not enough balance
  console.log("Insufficient funds. The total is " + total + "$ and you only have a balance of " + balance + "$.");
}
```

An additional check should be done to check if the voucher is bigger than the total.Generally using a voucher you loose the extra money of the voucher if it is bigger than the price, but in this situation I didn't added this check because it was not explicitly requested.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: @Keyan Try always to split your problem in simplest step as possible, than convert this steps to lines of code. This a simple rule (divide et impera)

Comment: Got it. The code you wrote definitely helps me see what you mean. Thank you for your tip!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes, here is the fixed version:

```
var total = 500;
var balance = 400;
var voucher = 100;
useVoucher = true;

if ( (total > balance) || (balance < 0) ) {
    console.log("Insufficient funds. The total is " + total + "$ and you only have a balance of " + balance + "$.");
} else if (useVoucher) {
    total = total - voucher
    console.log(voucher + "$ Voucher applied. The new total is " + total + "$.");
} else {
    console.log("You can't afford this item");
} 

if ((balance - total > 0) > 0 && balance > total) {
    console.log("Success! You have a new balance of " + (balance - total) + "$.");
}
```

1. Don't use a `;` in your `if` statements. It's not necessary and will result in your logic being executed incorrectly.
2. Don't do `(useVoucher = true)` this would assign the value `true` to the variable `useVoucher` rather than checking if it is `true`. Do `(useVoucher)` instead. This will check if `useVoucher` has a value which does not equal to `false`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That made it stop going below zero! I appreciate your explanation as well! I have a better understanding of it now. One thing, though: Can you explain your last edit with the “If (balance - total > 0) > 0 &&......” ? If the balance - total is larger than 0, and the larger than 0 is larger than zero? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your logic again. It seems like the voucher only gets used when there is sufficient amount of funds. I think you are supposed to remove the “else if” logic and type in the voucher usage in the first “if” block.

Comment: That did it! Many thanks for your awesome answer! How would you incorporate that into the first IF statement, though?

Comment: Take the logic from the “else if” and paste it there.

Comment: Sorry, I can’t show you a snippet as i am answering from a phone.

Comment: Do us a favor and select an answer keyan. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
debugger;
var total = 500;
var balance = 400;
var voucher = 100;
var balanceWithVoucher = balance + voucher;
total > balance ? useVoucher = true : useVoucher = false;


if ((total > balance && total > balanceWithVoucher) || (balance < 0)) {
    console.log("Insufficient funds. The total is " + total + "$ and you only have a balance of " + balance + "$.");
} else if (useVoucher == true) {
    total = total - voucher
    console.log(voucher + "$ Voucher applied. The new total is " + total + "$.");
} else {
    console.log("You can't afford this item");
}
if ((balance - total > 0) && balance > total); {
    console.log("Success! You have a new balance of " + (balance - total) + "$.");
}
```